# Not all XML data importing into ACCESS

Tags: xml, ms-access

I am trying to import this XML file into MS Access but it ignores the "TICKET" data and just pulls in the "SUB" tables of Ticket Details, Customers, ETC...   Don't know much about XML just trial and error.

Here is the file I am trying to import:

```
<SMS_TICKETS_EXPORT>
    <Ticket
        Number="32271"
        TicketDate="2001-06-22T16:01:08"
        TruckID="DWY15          "
        Trailer="               "
        CustomerID="BRE20          "
        OrderNumber="200101         "
        Material="360.77"
        Delivery="0.00"
        Misc="0.00"
        Tax="0.00"
        Paid=" "
        CheckNumber="0"
        InvoiceNumber="0"
        OperatorID="SEAN    "
        Miles="0"
        OverCap="N"
        OverCust="N"
        JobNo="0"
        Received="0.00"
        Pass="1"
        Status="0"
        Void="N"
        Replacement="N"
        ReplacedTicket="0"
        Remarks="Thank you for your business"
        DateTimeUpdated="2011-09-02T10:42:13.513"
        SiteNumber="1"
        ShipTo="0"
        CloseTimeStamp="2001-06-22T16:01:08">
        <Truck>
            <TruckID>DWY15          </TruckID>
            <Description>DWY #15                       </Description>
            <Tare>35020.00</Tare>
            <ContainerSize>0.00</ContainerSize>
            <EntryDate>1998-12-17T00:00:00</EntryDate>
            <TrailerAttached>N</TrailerAttached>
            <MaxWeight>60.00</MaxWeight>
            <Registration></Registration>
            <Comment></Comment>
            <SplitWeightCode>0</SplitWeightCode>
            <CustomerID>THA10          </CustomerID>
            <HaulerID></HaulerID>
            <UDFData1 />
            <UDFData2 />
            <VehicleType>TRUCK</VehicleType>
            <Created>2020-03-17T15:26:39.7130000</Created>
            <Modified>2020-03-17T15:26:39.7130000</Modified>
            <Sites>1</Sites>
        </Truck>
        <Customer>
            <CustomerID>BRE20          </CustomerID>
            <Name>BREWSTER TRANSIT              </Name>
            <Address1>P.O. BOX 410                  </Address1>
            <Address2></Address2>
            <City>BREWSTER                      </City>
            <State>NY                  </State>
            <Zip>10509     </Zip>
            <Country>U.S.A.                        </Country>
            <Contact>JEFF CHATTEN                  </Contact>
            <Phone>8452793738</Phone>
            <CreditLim>0.00</CreditLim>
            <CreditStatus>OK  </CreditStatus>
            <TaxExempt>Y</TaxExempt>
            <CurrentBalance>0.00</CurrentBalance>
            <Miles>0</Miles>
            <GLNumber></GLNumber>
            <DiscountLevel>0</DiscountLevel>
            <InvoiceTerms>0</InvoiceTerms>
            <BalanceForward>0.00</BalanceForward>
            <InvoiceByOrder>N</InvoiceByOrder>
            <Deposit>0.00</Deposit>
            <Notes>FIRST DAY W/ GOOD 3/4 3/19/01</Notes>
            <Fax></Fax>
            <Email />
            <UDFData1 />
            <UDFData2 />
            <CreditWarning>0</CreditWarning>
            <Sites>1</Sites>
            <AccountType>CUSTOMER</AccountType>
            <Created>2020-03-17T15:26:39.7530000</Created>
            <Modified>2020-03-17T15:26:39.7530000</Modified>
            <AllowCCTrans>Y</AllowCCTrans>
            <AllowCheckTrans>Y</AllowCheckTrans>
            <AllowCashTrans>Y</AllowCashTrans>
        </Customer>
        <Orders>
            <CustomerID>BRE20          </CustomerID>
            <OrderNum>200101         </OrderNum>
            <Description>BREWSTER PLANT F.O.B.         </Description>
            <Edate>2001-06-06T00:00:00</Edate>
            <Address1>P.O. BOX 410                  </Address1>
            <Address2></Address2>
            <City>BREWSTER                      </City>
            <State>NEW YORK            </State>
            <Zip>10509     </Zip>
            <Status>C</Status>
            <TaxRatePct>0.000</TaxRatePct>
            <TaxLocale></TaxLocale>
            <TaxExempt>N</TaxExempt>
            <TnLimit>0.000</TnLimit>
            <UnitLimit>0.000</UnitLimit>
            <Pricing>N</Pricing>
            <Miles>0</Miles>
            <LocationID></LocationID>
            <LimitPeriod>A</LimitPeriod>
            <Remarks />
            <AnyMaterial>Y</AnyMaterial>
            <Metric>N</Metric>
            <CostCode>0</CostCode>
            <AmountRcvd>0.00</AmountRcvd>
            <EscrowFwd>0.00</EscrowFwd>
            <EscrowMinimum>0.00</EscrowMinimum>
            <EscrowOrderSw>N</EscrowOrderSw>
            <EscrowWarning>0.00</EscrowWarning>
            <TonsWarning>0</TonsWarning>
            <UnitsWarning>0</UnitsWarning>
            <UDFData1 />
            <UDFData2 />
            <ShipTo>0</ShipTo>
            <InvoiceTerms>0</InvoiceTerms>
            <Created>2020-03-17T15:26:39.8230000</Created>
            <Modified>2020-03-17T15:26:39.8230000</Modified>
        </Orders>
        <TKDetail>
            <NUMBER>32271</NUMBER>
            <LINENUMBER>1</LINENUMBER>
            <TRUCKID>DWY15          </TRUCKID>
            <CUSTOMERID>BRE20          </CUSTOMERID>
            <ORDERNUMBER>200101         </ORDERNUMBER>
            <MATERIALID>SS10           </MATERIALID>
            <LOCATIONID></LOCATIONID>
            <MATERIALPRICE>8.6000</MATERIALPRICE>
            <MATERIALLABEL>tn </MATERIALLABEL>
            <DELIVERYCHARGE>0.0000</DELIVERYCHARGE>
            <DELIVERYCODE>Q</DELIVERYCODE>
            <MISCCHARGES>0.0000</MISCCHARGES>
            <QUANTITY>0.000</QUANTITY>
            <QUANTITYLABEL>tn </QUANTITYLABEL>
            <NET>83900.00</NET>
            <MATERIALTOTAL>360.77</MATERIALTOTAL>
            <DELIVERYTOTAL>0.00</DELIVERYTOTAL>
            <MISCTOTAL>0.00</MISCTOTAL>
            <TAXTOTAL>0.00</TAXTOTAL>
            <SYSTEMTAX>0.00</SYSTEMTAX>
            <ORDERTAX>0.00</ORDERTAX>
            <LOCATIONTAX>0.00</LOCATIONTAX>
            <MINIMUM>0.00</MINIMUM>
            <RESTRICTED>N</RESTRICTED>
            <TAX>Y</TAX>
            <Gross>120940.00</Gross>
            <GrossScale>-1</GrossScale>
            <GrossDateTime>2001-06-22T16:01:08</GrossDateTime>
            <Tare>37040.00</Tare>
            <TareScale>0</TareScale>
            <TareDateTime>2001-06-22T00:00:00</TareDateTime>
            <ContainerID></ContainerID>
            <Notes></Notes>
            <Direction>O</Direction>
            <DeliveryCost>0.0000</DeliveryCost>
            <MaterialCost>0.0000</MaterialCost>
            <Material>
                <MaterialID>SS10           </MaterialID>
                <Description>NYS SPEC. CONCRETE SAND       </Description>
                <MaterialPrice>22.5000</MaterialPrice>
                <MaterialLabel>tn </MaterialLabel>
                <MaterialCost>0.0000</MaterialCost>
                <MaterialGL></MaterialGL>
                <ConversionFactor>0.0000000</ConversionFactor>
                <MinimumCharge>0.00</MinimumCharge>
                <DeliveryCharge>0.0000</DeliveryCharge>
                <DeliveryCost>0.0000</DeliveryCost>
                <DeliveryGL></DeliveryGL>
                <DeliveryCode>Q</DeliveryCode>
                <MiscCharges>0.0000</MiscCharges>
                <Taxable>Y</Taxable>
                <Direction>O</Direction>
                <Restricted>N</Restricted>
                <MTCategory></MTCategory>
                <UDFData1 />
                <UDFData2 />
                <Inactive></Inactive>
                <LoadAdjustment>0.0000000</LoadAdjustment>
                <Created>2020-03-17T15:26:39.7770000</Created>
                <Modified>2020-03-17T15:26:39.7770000</Modified>
                <DefaultQuantity>0.000</DefaultQuantity>
                <Sites>1</Sites>
            </Material>
            <Rate>
                <CustomerID>BRE20          </CustomerID>
                <OrderNum>200101         </OrderNum>
                <MaterialID>SS10           </MaterialID>
                <MaterialPrice>8.6000</MaterialPrice>
                <MaterialCost>0.0000</MaterialCost>
                <MinimumCharge>0.00</MinimumCharge>
                <DeliveryCharge>0.0000</DeliveryCharge>
                <DeliveryCost>0.0000</DeliveryCost>
                <DeliveryCode>Q</DeliveryCode>
                <QtyOrdered>0.000</QtyOrdered>
                <DiscountBase>0.00</DiscountBase>
                <DiscountInc>0.00</DiscountInc>
                <DiscountAmount>0.0000</DiscountAmount>
                <DefaultMaterial>N</DefaultMaterial>
                <Created>2020-03-17T15:26:39.8800000</Created>
                <Modified>2020-03-17T15:26:39.8800000</Modified>
            </Rate>
        </TKDetail>
    </Ticket>
</SMS_TICKETS_EXPORT>
```

All I get are these tables but the data for the ticket is not here:
[Tables in MS ACCESS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkMv7.png)

Answer (score 0):

MS Access' `ImportXML` (or Ribbon feature) only imports element-centric content and not attribute-centric as the `Ticket` node contains unlike other nodes. Consider transforming your XML to move attributes to elements with [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/) (special-purpose language designed to transform XML files) prior to import:

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl, a special .xml file)*

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Ticket/@*">
    <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bET2rWT)</kbd>

**VBA** *(two methods of Access object library and VBA MSXML library)*

```vb
Public Sub XMLHandle1() 
   ' RUN XSLT TRANSFORMATION
    Application.TransformXML "C:\Path\To\Input.xml", _
                             "C:\Path\To\Transform.xsl", _
                             "C:\Path\To\Output.xml"

    ' IMPORT TRANSFORMED VERSION
    Application.ImportXML "C:\Path\To\Output.xml"
End Sub
```

```vb
Public Sub XMLHandle2()
    Dim xmlDoc As Object, xslDoc As Object, newDoc As Object

    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Set xslDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Set newDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

    ' LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
    xmlDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\Input.xml"
    xmlDoc.async = False

    xslDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\Transform.xsl"
    xslDoc.async = False

    ' RUN XSLT TRANSFORMATION
    xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
    newDoc.Save "C:\Path\To\Output.xml"

    ' IMPORT TRANSFORMED VERSION
    Application.ImportXML "C:\Path\To\Output.xml"

    Set newDoc = Nothing: Set xslDoc = Nothing: Set xmlDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```